# If statement for a specific value in a range doesn't work properly?

Tags: excel, vba

this is my code:

```
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A13")
    If cell.Value = "Totals" Then

    Else
        Sheets(1).Range("A2:G4").Select
        Selection.Copy
        wb2.Activate
        Sheets(1).Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next cell
```

I wanted it to do nothing after `Then`, but even if it finds the word 'Totals', it still runs the code after `Else`. What I want is that if the word 'totals' is there in that range, then do nothing.

Comment: Does your range contain any cells that don't show `"Totals"`? You're running your `If` statement for every single cell in your range, so I'm guessing that at least one `cell.Value` isn't `"Totals"` therefore your `Else` block is running. You should iterate to see if any single cell has `"Totals"` then, after checking all the cells in the range, decide if you're going to run your copy + paste. You could also use `Find` to do this without looping.

Comment: Your code checks 13 times `If cell.Value = "Totals"`, assuming only one value contains "Totals" your `Else` part of the if statement is run 12 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing your copy-pasting inside the loop and risking running it 13 times just set a flag once (if "Totals" is found) and run your code once after the loop like this:

```
Dim found as Boolean

For Each cell In Range("A1:A13")
    If cell.Value = "Totals" Then found = True
Next cell

If Not found then
    Sheets(1).Range("A2:G4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb2.Activate
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

And please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/8769365) to get rid of `Select` and `Activate` as it is error-prone.